# render a page to a file with rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I have a background process that loads a Rails 3.0 environment.  I would like to have that process refresh cached pages instead of having to wait for them to be loaded the first time.  How could I take a set of `params` push it through the render pipeline to the point where I could direct the plain html to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 3.0 is a Rack Application. You can use a Rack Middleware to do it. Take a look a [Rack::Deflater::GzipStream](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Deflater/GzipStream.html) for a code sample and [Rails on Rack](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html) for the RoR specific parts.